# Rails 4 JQuery functions returning 'is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to do a Nested Form and I'm using the RailsCast method.  All seems well except for the any JQuery functions do not work.  Putting a breakpoint and stepping through on the code I can see it jumps into jquery.js, so I can see it at least know what $ means.  However, it looks like it doesn't find any of the functions.

Trying to execute: 
    `$(link).up().insert({ before: content.replace(regexp, new_id) });`

Its says $(...).up is not a function.

Simple things like hide() so the same thing.  I'm not sure even how to debug this.  I know how do to the hide using 'normal' javascript but not sure how to the the above function to insert the new content.  Any ideas?

Edit 10:37am:
OK JasonP pointed out that the tutorial is Prototype not JQuery.  Since we use JQuery and NOT Prototype, any idea how to morph that line above into JQuery?

Comment: in your browser console, what does $(link) return?

Comment: Is jQuery loaded at all?

Comment: `$().up()` isn't a function in any version of jquery I can see.

Comment: Are you using any `jQuery` plugins? What's `.up()` indeed?

Comment: Looks like you're mixing jQuery and Prototype: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/up/. I think `parent()`, `parents()`, or `closest()` would be the jQuery version, depending on exactly what you want to do.

Comment: JasonP, looks like you're right, looking at the tutorial, it is Prototype! I just alsowasy assume $. is Jquery.

Comment: Perhaps the syntax your looking for is `$(link).parent().before()`

Comment: @RossR It's not always. That's why `jQuery.noConflict` and the `(function($) { ... })(jQuery)` pattern exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the jQuery syntax you're looking for is

`$(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id))`

and I do hope that `link` variable is proper, too

Get the parent of the `link` and insert before it what `content` is

If you want to insert inside the parent instead of `.before()` use `.prepend()` or `.append()`

Comment: That works like a champ!  Thank everyone and sorry for the prototype misstep.